# Multiply value, round down and CAST Select in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL function that gathers labour times from multiple records, and uses `STUFF(CAST AS VARCHAR(20))` to concatenate them into a single column in a temp table.

My issue is the labour values in my table are in hours and rounded down to 7 decimals, I want to convert those values to minutes and round them down to 2 decimals before stuffing them into my temp table.

**Update:** Forgot to mention, I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

Here is my code.

```
  @site nvarchar(20)
  ,@item nvarchar(30)
  ,@enviro nvarchar(30))
RETURNS nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LbrHours AS nvarchar(MAX) = ''

    IF @enviro = 'Test'
    BEGIN
        IF @site = 'Arborg'
        BEGIN
            SET @LbrHours = STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(jrt.run_lbr_hrs AS VARCHAR(20))
                            FROM Arborg_Test_App.dbo.jobroute AS jbr
                                INNER JOIN Arborg_Test_App.dbo.job AS job
                                    ON job.job = jbr.job 
                                    AND job.suffix = jbr.suffix
                                INNER JOIN Arborg_Test_App.dbo.item AS itm
                                    ON itm.job = job.job
                                INNER JOIN Arborg_Test_App.dbo.jrt_sch AS jsh
                                    ON jbr.job = jsh.job 
                                    AND jbr.suffix = jsh.suffix 
                                    AND jbr.oper_num = jsh.oper_num
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN Arborg_Test_App.dbo.jrt_sch AS jrt
                                    ON jbr.job = jrt.job
                                    AND jbr.suffix = jrt.suffix
                                    AND jbr.oper_num = jrt.oper_num
                            WHERE  job.suffix = '0' and job.type = 'S' AND itm.item IS NOT NULL
                                AND itm.item = @item 
                                AND jbr.suffix = CASE -- Return Standard cost if Standard Operation exist, else return current cost
                                                    WHEN itm.cost_type = 'S'
                                                        THEN '1' -- '1' for standard operation
                                                    ELSE '0' -- '0' for current operations
                                                  END
                            ORDER BY itm.item, jbr.oper_num
                            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
            END 
        END

    RETURN @LbrHours
END
```

`jrt.run_lbr_hrs` is the column that contains the labour times in hours in our ERP's table. How can I multiply that by 60 and round it down to 2 decimals with in my existing `STUFF(CASE AS NVARCHAR)`?

Comment: Looks like `SQL Server` from the syntax (use of `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF()` function)

Comment: Yeah SQL 2008 R2. Sorry, it's been a crazy day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CAST` to decimal with 2 value after the point and then to varchar

```
CAST(CAST(jrt.run_lbr_hrs * 60 AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS VARCHAR(20))
```

Change the decimal dimension to what you need

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I used `CAST(CAST(jrt.run_lbr_hrs * 60 AS DECIMAL(7, 2) AS VARCHAR(20)))` but I get "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'" for that line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this  `Str (jrt.run_lbr_hrs * 60, 2)`

Comment: Could you please add some explanation as to why your solution works?

Comment: It is a standart function of mssql server, in better way you may get small change of code to str (jrt.run_lbr_hrs * 60, 10, 2)